# Detect HTML anchor tag download selection

Tags: html, download, anchor

I use an anchor tag to provide my users with an option to download some client side generated data in a file. I use the following code:

```
function GenerateTextFile (FileType, FileName, FileContents)
{
var data = new Blob ([FileContents], {type: 'text/plain'});
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL (data);
var link = document.createElement ("a");
link.download  = FileName + "." + FileType ;
link.href      = url ;
link.innerText = " Click here to download" ;
};
```

Later on I invoke the following to tidy up :

```
window.URL.revokeObjectURL (url);
```

Please can someone tell me how I can detect that the user has clicked on the anchor tag? I would like to either remove or change the text so that the download is not activated twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a click listener to the link. Or is there some reason you don’t want that?

```
link.onclick = function(){console.log("link was clicked");}
```

Comment: I just wondered whether the onclick function would override the default behaviour

Comment: No it doesn't. Unless you change it to `link.onclick = function(event){event.preventDefault(); console.log("link was clicked");}

Answer (score 1):

```js
function GenerateTextFile(FileType, FileName, FileContents) {
  var data = new Blob([FileContents], {
    type: 'text/plain'
  });
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = FileName + "." + FileType;
  link.href = url;
  link.innerText = " Click here to download";
  link.id = Date.now();
  link.setAttribute("onclick", "removeDownload('" + link.id + "')");
  let links = document.getElementById("links");
  links.appendChild(link);
};

function removeDownload(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).remove();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="GenerateTextFile('txt','test','lorem ipsum');">Create Dummy DL</button>

<div id="links"></div>
```

Note: The download of the file won't work within the snippet. It works outside of the sandbox though. This uses the `onclick` event of the `a` element with a dynamic `id` (epoch) which then just calls the `removeDownload` method, which will get the a element by its `id` and remove it.